# How to monitor each thread behavior of a multithread (pthread) C++ program on Linux ?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, debugging, pthreads

I am running a multithread (pthread) C++ program on Linux (redhat).

I want to follow the behavior of the running program but the print-out from threads interleave with each other. It is hard to find out the behavior of each thread.

I want to use DDD (a gdb GUI) to analyze the behavior of the program but it needs "motif", when I install "motif", which has an error:

cc -c  -O -I../../include -I../../imports/x11/include/X11 `./ccimake` imake.c
imake.c:162:21: error: Xosdefs.h: No such file or directory

I also used helgrind and drd tools but there are a lot of plain text print-out, which makes it confusing the behavior of each thread.

Would you please recommend better open-source tools that can help me do debug and analyze/monitor behavior of multiple pthreads clearly and easily ?

Is it possible to show each thread in a distinct terminal xterm window w/o mixing up all threads together ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried running multiple `gdb` instances, each in a different xterm and attached to a different thread?

Comment: @Borealid, I want but i do not know how to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you just want to isolate a particular thread in your log prefix each log message with something unique to each thread (e.g. pthread_self) and then grep the log with that prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The standard print functions like printf are not thread safe. If you are logging to stdout or a single file, you need to treat your logging functions as critical section and protect them using mutex. Otherwise your log could be interleaved or out of order.

Alternatively you can let each thread create their own log file, write thread name/id and timestamp to each file, and "tail" those log files in separate terminals.

Comment: While it is true that the *C* standard does not specify threads, *POSIX* pthreads requires stdio functions to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure to use `printf` for printing, then at least the lines will be printed intact
- Make sure each thread uses a prefix, like `[MainThread] Log message...`
- Direct output to a file: `your_program > logfile.txt`
- For each thread, do: `tail -f logfile.txt | grep <thread_prefix>`